# configure nginx to so all domain can /phpmyadmin

Tags: nginx, debian, php-fpm, debian-jessie, phpmyadmin

I'm triyng to setup nginx so every vhost can access phpmyadmin like so
`example.com/phpmyadmin`
I tried using this configuration but no luck
this is my default file

```
server {
    #return 404;
        location /phpmyadmin {
               root /usr/share/nginx/phpmyadmin/;
               index index.php index.html index.htm;
               location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
                       try_files $uri =404;
                       root /usr/share/nginx/phpmyadmin/;
                       fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
                       fastcgi_index index.php;
                       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                       include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
               }
               location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
                       root /usr/share/nginx/phpmyadmin/;
               }
        }
        location /phpMyAdmin {
               rewrite ^/* /phpmyadmin last;
        }
}
```

thanks.

Comment: What did you expect to happen? What happened instead?  Do you have any log entries from the times it didn't work as expected?

Comment: 404, no relevant log, expected phpmyadmin

Comment: Why do you want to make it easy for attackers to find phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far I know, nginx don't allow share location between servers. You should add phpmyadmin location in each server section(for each domains) or configure nginx to listen on additional port(e.g. `listen 88`) and configure there location for phpmyadmin, to have it on all domains, but on another port.

Comment: that plus omitting phpmyadmin from root helped

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you'll need to set those `location /phpmyadmin {...}` directives for each  server, each virtual host, you can't set them once and be active for all `server {}` blocks.

The easiest is probably to create an `phpmyadmin.include` file which you load from every server:

```
# conf/phpmyadmin.conf
location /phpmyadmin {
           root /usr/share/nginx/phpmyadmin/;
           index index.php index.html index.htm;
           location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
                   try_files $uri =404;
                   root /usr/share/nginx/phpmyadmin/;
                   fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
                   fastcgi_index index.php;
                   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                   include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
           }
           location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
                   root /usr/share/nginx/phpmyadmin/;
           }
}
location /phpMyAdmin {
           rewrite ^/* /phpmyadmin last;
}
```

and then

```
server { 
  listen       80;
  server_name  example.com www.example.com;
  include      conf/phpmyadmin.conf;
}
server { 
  listen       80;
  server_name  example.org www.example.org;
  include      conf/phpmyadmin.conf;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use `alias` rather than rooting to `/phpmyadmin/` directory because of security reasons.

and its possible to add an alias to nginx default config file (located in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`) after line `server_name _;` this way:

```
location /secretpath {
    alias /usr/share/phpmyadmin/;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    location ~ ^/secretpath(.+\.php)$ {
        alias /usr/share/phpmyadmin$1;
      #### here I'm using php8.2 with php8.2-fpm beside nginx webserver
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock; #OR fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/phpmyadmin$1;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors        on;
    }
}
```

and then you can use urls like `http://anyhosteddomain.com/secretpath` to access phpmyadmin.
You need to use `http` protocol rather than `https` here because of lacking a fixed domain name for including certificates in this method.